# How to identify a LogGroup is AWS service LogGroup or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using AWS Cloudwatch to store my application logs. Logs are generated by some of the AWS services(Glue, Crawlers, Lambda, EKS, ECS, etc.) are also stored in CloudWatch automatically. I also have custom log groups that I have created.

I would like to differentiate AWS Service LogGroups and Custom LogGroups.

Answer (score 0):

Tag your log groups with a custom tag. Tags are your friend when it comes to resource grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Any log groups created by AWS service will have a standard naming convention like `/aws/lambda/[log-group-name]`

You can create your custom log group names anything else you like. Not starting them with /aws/ is the general convention.